# Problem with subscripts in custom xparse commands from foreign files

Tags: macros, xparse

When compiling this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{testPackage}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mm}{#1_{#2}}

\begin{document}
$\foo A i$, $\fooT A i$
\end{document}
```

where `testPackage` includes the definition:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
...
\ExplSyntaxOn
...
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooT}{mm}{#1_{#2}}
...
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I get the output:

[image]

Why is the subscript not typesetted correctly in the second version, even though both commands do the same?

Comment: ??? `\fooT` and `\foo` look the same for me? And the output is the same

Comment: What is the category code is `_` in `testPackage`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for being unclear. But somehow you read my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the O.P. has `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` as a wrapper around the definition of `\fooT`. This will change the catcodes of course and `_` is interpreted differently.

If none of the `expl3` syntax (e.g. think of `\cs_new:N` etc.) is needed, don't use `\ExplSyntax...`. The `\NewDocumentCommand` is sufficient for this!

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{testPackage}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooT}{mm}{#1_{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooother}{mm}{#1_{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mm}{#1_{#2}}

\begin{document}
$\foo{A}{i}$, $\fooT{A}{i}$, $\fooother{A}{i}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The conventions holding between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are, essentially:

1. spaces and end-of-lines are ignored (but not in the middle of a control sequence name, of cours)
2. `_` and `:` can (and should) be part of control sequence names, so they have category code 11 (letter)
3. `~` is the same as an ordinary space token

A consequence of this is that `_` cannot be used to introduce subscripts in math mode. The reason is the usual one: if you do

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooT}{mm}{#1_{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

the replacement text of `\fooT` is tokenized when `_` is a letter, so it will be such every time `\fooT` is called.

In order to solve this problem, the `expl3` kernel provides

```
\c_math_subscript_token
```

so you should use it when you need `_`8 in the body of a definition, either for introducing a subscript or for checking with `\peek_...` tests.

Using `\sb` is also possible, which might be more attractive in the code above; so

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooA}{mm}{#1\c_math_subscript_token{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

or

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooA}{mm}{#1\sb{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

are equivalent. The former syntax should preferably be used in a pure `expl3` context.

Comment: “*The former syntax should preferably be used in a pure expl3 context.*” I don't think the use of that `_token` is this one so may be not even in “pure expl3 context” would be necessary. When a math package is released may be something like `\math_subscript:n {#2}` could be preferred.

Comment: @Manuel There's quite a big difference between `_` (or `\c_math_subscript_token`) and a macro, because `_` looks for a `<filler>`.

Comment: I didn't mean it was the same. I meant that `\c_math_subscript_token` wasn't designed for this (IMO), i.e., to be used as a subscript; altough it's expl3 it doesn't make it fit for this. If there was a `\math_subscript:n` then *that* “should preferably be used in a pure expl3 context”. I was just nitpicking that I don't think using `_token` as a subscript in this case is preferred in expl3 at all.

Answer (score 2):

If, for some reason, you need to use a subscript inside expl3 syntax, you can always use `\sb`

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooT}{mm}{#1\sb{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```